# Authentication Failure on Github even after adding SSH key

Tags: github, ssh

I get fatal:Authenication Failure when I try to push code to my repo. I've added the public key on my github account as well. When I do :
    `ssh -i git@github.com`

I get 
    `Hi amangupta052! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.`

Can anyone help?
Thanks

Answer (score 44, accepted):

That depends on the remote url you have used.

If `git remote -v` returns:

```
https://github.com/username/reponame
```

Then your ssh setup won't matter. But this would work:

```
ssh://git@github.com:username/reponame
```

Another cause is linked to your private key: if it is pass-phrase protected, with a special character in it, that usually don't work well.
[See here for other ssh causes of failure](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11525564/6309).

---

To replace your remote named `origin`, use [`git remote`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-remote) commands:

```
git remote set-url origin ssh://git@github.com:username/reponame
```

(as explained in the [GitHub help page](https://help.github.com/articles/why-is-git-always-asking-for-my-password) about [changing the rmeote url](https://help.github.com/articles/changing-a-remote-s-url))

If you see::

```
ssh: Could not resolve hostname github.com:amangupta052: 
     Name or service not known 
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

Try the non-scp ssh syntax:

```
git remote set-url origin ssh://git@github.com/username/reponame
```

(note the '`/`' instead of the '`:`' after `github.com`)

Maybe this would have worked, as [commented in this blog post](http://kuttler.eu/post/git-clone-ssh-could-not-resolve-hostname/):

```
git remote set-url origin git@github.com:username/reponame
```

(scp-like syntax, but without the `ssh://` prefix)

As [I mention here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14423667/6309), an scp syntax usually means an `~/.ssh/config` file to work properly.

Comment: Ok so my origin is https one, how can I get the ssh origin? I'm sorry I'm really new to git.

Comment: @AmanGupta no problem, I have edited my answer. Replace '`username`' and '`reponame`' by the appropriate values.

Comment: Ok, I set the new origin. I get ssh on doing git remote -v. But now, I get
    `ssh: Could not resolve hostname github.com:amangupta052: Name or service not known
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly` on doing `git push`

Comment: @AmanGupta is that the output of the `git remote set-url` command, or of the `git push` you could do just after?

Comment: @AmanGupta but you accepted the answer, does that mean the `git push` finally worked?

Comment: haha, no I thought you'd have the answer in your next comment!

Comment: @AmanGupta  I have edited the answer to address your error message on `git push`.

Comment: I enabled two factor authentication, and suddenly started to receive this error. Apparently, https does not work with two factor auth, so if you enable that it is a good idea to switch to the ssh based login.

Comment: @joscarsson 2FA (2 Form Authentication) should work with https without any issue: you need to gneerate a PAT (Personal Access Token). See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13800289/configure-git-clients-like-github-for-windows-to-not-ask-for-authentication/18607931#18607931.

Comment: i've set up SSH key and agent in my laptop and the connection to github was working properly but i still received the authentication error msg when using git push. 

Using your method ssh://git@github.com:username/reponame and replacing ':' with a slash worked for me.